# How to display mySQL data to label in C#

Tags: c#, mysql, label

Hi I'm currently having a problem in displaying data from mySQL database to labels in c#. Well, in my database, i have 6 columns and i want to call specific data from the 5th column by restricting it using the 6th column. My column names are count, fullname, position, year, course, partylist, and numparty. Why can't the data be displayed on the label? Can somebody help me out.

```
 string myConnection = "datasource=localhost;port=3307;username=root;password=root";
            MySqlConnection myConn = new MySqlConnection(myConnection);
            MySqlCommand command = myConn.CreateCommand();
            command.CommandText = "Select `Partylist` FROM expertsystem.addcandidate WHERE `NumParty`=1";
            MySqlDataReader myReader;

         try
            {
                myConn.Open();
                myReader = command.ExecuteReader();

                 while (myReader.Read())
        {
            lblpartylist1.Text = myReader[5].ToString();

            }
         }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }
            myConn.Close();
```

Answer (score 2):

The index of myReader[5] represent the index of your select.

Could you try this :

```
string myConnection = "datasource=localhost;port=3307;username=root;password=root";
            MySqlConnection myConn = new MySqlConnection(myConnection);
            MySqlCommand command = myConn.CreateCommand();
            command.CommandText = "Select Partylist FROM expertsystem.addcandidate WHERE NumParty=1";
            MySqlDataReader myReader;

         try
            {
                myConn.Open();
                myReader = command.ExecuteReader();

                 while (myReader.Read())
        {
            lblpartylist1.Text = myReader[0].ToString();

            }
         }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }
            myConn.Close();
```

Comment: Could you place a breakpoint in your catch to show if the execution don't throw an exception.

Comment: @IamMe Or you can try a MessageBox.Show(myReader.HasRows); after the ExecuteReader to show if the query return a row

Comment: @lamMe. Could you try the code of the previous comment ?

Answer (score 0):

**Problem :** You are only fetching cloumn name `Partylist` from your table but you are trying to access the 6th column , which is not there.

**Solution 1:** You need to fetch all columns from your table.

Replace This:

```
 Select `Partylist` FROM
```

With This:

```
 Select * FROM
```

**Solution 2:** You need to change index value from 5 to 0 .

Replace This:

```
 lblpartylist1.Text = myReader[5].ToString();
```

With This:

```
 lblpartylist1.Text = myReader[0].ToString();
```

**Solution 3:**

You did not assign the Connection object `myConn` to your command object `command` before executing the command.

Try This:

```
try
{
  myConn.Open();
  command.Connection = myConn;  //add this statement
  myReader = command.ExecuteReader();
```

**Suggestion :** Your query is open to sql injection attacks please consider using parameterised queries to avoid them.

Comment: thanks! I've tried your suggestion but it still doesn't display what i wanted to. Also, I had called "Partylist" because i only need specific column.  I couldn't really find the problem here.

Comment: I tried what you've suggested and sad to say, it still display nothing. If there's other option please do let me know.

Comment: @IamMe.: check my `solution3` , You did not assign the Connection object `myConn` to your command object command before executing the `command`.

Comment: Did that too. It doesn't help either.

Comment: @Downvoter : could you please explain me the problem?

Comment: @IamMe.: are you sure your connection string works? because default mysql port number is `3306` change it and try

Answer (score 0):

Try To do this way, This is how i read a column to fill in my text boxes, Of course, replace the Column_Name with the real name of the column you want in you database.

```
lblpartylist1.Text = myReader.GetString("Column_Name");
```

Good luck